# Django append to JSON after serializers.serialze has been run on a queryset

Tags: django, json, append

I am returning a JSON serialized queryset using the following queryset:

```
genome_parents = Genome.objects.filter(genes=cus_id)
```

where cus_id is the FK pointing to a companies table so I am retrieving all Genome objects related to the current working company. I return this data after a form has been posted via:

```
genome_parents = serializers.serialize('json', genome_parents, use_natural_keys=True)
```

However, I need the natural key for one of my foreign keys, but the id for another (both on the same model). So one field is displayed nicely, but the other isn't. So this does what I need except for one little thing, I need the plain id number so that I can pre-populate my FK form field.

One thought I had was to just append something like

```
genome_parents.append({'id':gene.id})
```

but that obviously doesn't work. Is there anyway I can augment the JSON so that I can include one more little piece of data (or change how I format the JSON)?

Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just switch the order of the operations.  And put the entire `gene` object into the list so it is properly serialized.

```
genome_parents = list( Genome.objects.filter(genes=cus_id) )
genome_parents.append(gene)

json_genome_parents = serializers.serialize('json', genome_parents, use_natural_keys=True)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is just what I needed. list() is the key.